# tab in a tab, onActivityResult not called

Tags: android, tabs

I'm having a problem with the onActivityResult() method not being called. I suspect this is somehow due to the fact that the activity calling startActivityForResult() is in a tab which in turn is in another tab. Most of the code is in fact identical to a previous version in which the calling activity was just a tab (rather than a tab in a tab), and that version works just fine. Are there special considerations to keep in mind in this kind of circumstance?

Manu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be a "proper" answer, but I've had several commercial products start using Tabs with TabActivity, and before the end, we had ripped them out and simulated tabs with buttons.  For anything non-trivial, TabActivity turns out to be a mess.  I can't imagine nested tabs.

My 2 cents.